# Integer json Object json in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json

I have json result which contain set of json objects.I could not get json object because json object is in integer value.Here is my json result

```
{
    "hotnumber": {
        "1": {
            "Rank": 1,
            "Total": "11",
            "Number": "39",
            "First": "4",
            "Second": "4",
            "Third": "3"
        },
        "2": {
            "Rank": 2,
            "Total": "10",
            "Number": "25",
            "First": "2",
            "Second": "4",
            "Third": "4"
        },
        "3": {
            "Rank": 3,
            "Total": "10",
            "Number": "34",
            "First": "3",
            "Second": "3",
            "Third": "4"
        },
        "4": {
            "Rank": 4,
            "Total": "9",
            "Number": "65",
            "First": "2",
            "Second": "5",
            "Third": "2"
        },
        "5": {
            "Rank": 5,
            "Total": "9",
            "Number": "84",
            "First": "4",
            "Second": "3",
            "Third": "2"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code what i tried

```
$http({
                        url : baseUrl,
                        method :'Post',
                        data : param
                    }) 
                    .success(function (result) {  
            $scope.rank =result.hotnumber.1.Rank;  

}
```

Is there anyway to get json objects? help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `$scope.rank =result.hotnumber["1"].Rank;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for string as a key ("1" is a string), use brackets notation:

```
$http({
                    url : baseUrl,
                    method :'Post',
                    data : param
                }) 
                .success(function (result) {  
        $scope.rank = result.hotnumber["1"].Rank;  

}
```

notice **hotnumber["1"]** instead of **hotnumber.1**